# Continued fraction of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, continued-fractions

There is this 
$$\exp(x)=1+\cfrac{x}{1-\cfrac{x/2}{1+x/2-\cfrac{x/3}{1+x/3-\cfrac{x/4}{1+x/4-\dots}}}}$$
and there is 
$$\exp(1)=1+\cfrac{1}{0+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{\cdots}}}}}}$$

Is there a way to rewrite the second equation, replacing some numbers with expressions $x$, so that we get something like the first equation, valid in a neighborhood of $1$, and such that, plugging in $x$, recovers the second equation?

I tried something like 
$$1+x+x^2/2+\cdots=1+\cfrac{x}{0+\cfrac{1}{?}}$$
as well as a few other guesses, but found it difficult.

Comment: This - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula#Euler.27s_formula - will help. You can get this by the Euler's formula.

Comment: No. I know how to derive the first equation. I wanted to extend the second equation.

Comment: It seems not even trivial to go from the first to the second. It's not just to set $x=1$.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes! The first and second equation seem to be very different. I want to find a third equation, that looks kind of like the first equation, with $exp(x)=$ some continued fraction, such that when plugging $x=1$, gets the second equation.

Comment: An existence of a general transformation from an Euler-formula generalized continued fraction representation to a simple continued fraction representation would resolve a lot of open questions on rationality so I'm skeptical any such route would work (or, if it does, it almost surely will need to appeal to some specific-to-this-representation property).

Comment: Before I decided the above and ran out of time to work on this I took this transformation from the first representation in case somebody wants to look for such a special property. Using the notation $\displaystyle\DeclareMathOperator*{\K}{K}e^x=b_0+\K_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$, $b_0,b_1=1$, $a_1=x$, and for $n\geq 2$, $a_n=-x$ and $b_n=(x+n)(n-2)!!/(n-1)!!$. I was next going to transform $-x\to x$ when I realized my previous comment. Note that while that transformation will add some "$1$"" terms similar to the expansion you want it will not deal with the fractions.

Comment: After $8$ terms, still agrees very well with $e^x$ in a neighborhood of $0$: http://i.imgur.com/YgTDGUV.png

Comment: @GPhys Good. I actually got that result myself too. I should edit the question to include that part in.

Comment: The coefficients of $x^{-1}$ are $1,3,5,\ldots$:
$$e^x=
1
+\cfrac{1}{x^{-1}-1
+\cfrac{1}{1
+\cfrac{1}{1
+\cfrac{1}{3x^{-1}-1
+\cfrac{1}{1
+\cfrac{1}{\cdots}}}}}}$$

I think this answers the question? I'm not sure it converges just *above* $1$ though

Comment: @GPhys How did you get that continued fraction with $x^{-1}$?

Comment: @MaudPieTheRocktorate It was in some notes of Euler's I was flipping through. I don't have time to find it again right now, but I think the context meant it for sure converges when $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x=1/n$.

Comment: You can guess it from the continued fractions of $\exp(1/n)$.  As I recall it can be proved as a special case of a for the continued fraction of a quotient of Bessel functions along the lines of http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.33